# Jekyll - How do I create pages in the root directory?

Tags: html, ruby, yaml, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to create a page and the docs suggest that Jekyll has the option to create pages in the root directory, or to create new directories for new pages.

**From http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/**

> Where you put HTML files for pages depends on how you want the pages
>   to work. There are two main ways of creating pages:
>
> - Place named HTML files for each page in your site’s root folder.
> - Create a folder in the site’s root for each page, and place an
>     index.html file in each page folder.

```
project
-- _includes
-- _site
---- about
------ index.html
----assets
------ css
------ img
------ js
--assets
---- css
---- img
---- js
-- _config.yml
-- about.html
-- index.html
```

How do I configure Jekyll to create pages in the root directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create an `about.html` page at the root of you Jekyll folder, it will generated in `_site/about.html` except if you put a [permalink](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) in the front matter.

By default the about page has a permalink (`permalink: /about/`) it is then generated in `_site/about/index.html`.

With permalink you can even do :

- page in `pages/mypage.html`
- `permalink: my-nice-page.html`
- generated at `_site/my-nice-page.html`

Note: If you set your global `permalink` in `_config.yml` to `pretty`, all pages will be generated in order to give pretty urls like http://domain.tld/about/ (in `_site/about/index.html`). You can the change this variable to date or other or put a permalink in your page to override the global one.

Comment: The only thing I have in the frontmatter is a title. If I remove this, Jekyll places the about.html file in the root directory. If it has a title, it creates an about/ directory with an index.html file.

Comment: I saw your `_config.yml`. The `permalink: pretty` tells Jekyll to generate pages in folders. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You place them in whatever your jekyll project folder is. So if you're folder is `myjekyllproject` then you'll add a file named index.html or about.html. From there you will do a `jekyll build`. Jekyll will then put include that file in your `myjekyllproject/_site folder`.

Comment: When I build, Jekyll is creating new directories. The output is /about/index.html rather than /about.html

Comment: In your project folder do you have an about folder with an index.html in it, or an about.html in just the project folder?

Comment: Based on that is looks like you have both an about.html and an about/index.html When you do a jekyll serve and go to http://localhost:4000/about.html and http://localhost:4000/about/ do those both display?

Comment: no... when I build, jekyll creates the /about directory and index file. It's not creating an about.html file.

Comment: Do you have frontmatter in the header of your about.html file?

Comment: yes, just the title and layout | Edit: that seemed to be the problem :( is there a way to use front-matter without Jekyll creating new directories?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68054/discussion-between-marc-k-and-aaron-benjamin).

Comment: Change the permalink to your liking. The way it is defined (or if you use the default), determines how the processed files are distributed. My `_config.yml` simply contains `permalink: date` and it keeps the same directory structure as the original.