# Links without .html extension with no need to create directories

Tags: html, ruby, markdown, jekyll

I am running website on Jekyll. I want to make links, like `contact` to `contact.md` (now I am using `contact.html` link) - that means I want to remove .html extension. I read this question - [How to link to a page with page.url without the html extension in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034994/how-to-link-to-a-page-without-html-extension-in-jekyll), but it tells to create directory for each folder. I do not like this idea - I want to have everything in one, main directory. Can you give my any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link to a page without html extension in Jekyll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034994/how-to-link-to-a-page-without-html-extension-in-jekyll) If such solution exists, it will be upvoted there ;-)

Answer (score 5):

That is correct. A static site *always* has to have a page to render. Most web servers are configured to look for `index.html` if you specify a directory.

If you were using an application server, like `Unicorn`, and serving dynamic then you can handle requests however you want, but web servers like Nginx and Apache will look for files on disk.

Thus:

`example.com/contact.html`

would actually become:

`example.com/contact/index.html`

But you could omit the filename, and the web server will figure it out:

`example.com/contact`

Answer (score 0):

[permalink](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) is your solution.

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27740429/1548376) for short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up permalink handling in Jekyll **any way you want**. First, look into Jekyll's built-in [permalink support](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) where a format of (just for example)

```
permalink: blah/:title
```

Or

```
permalink: /:categories/:title
```

will convince Jekyll to start emitting extensionless permalinks. Then to clean up the wasteful `/foo/index.html` structures created by Jekyll under that scheme, use something like Will Norris's [jekyll-clean-urls](https://github.com/willnorris/jekyll-clean-urls) (or my own [jekyll-simple-urls](https://github.com/codingthewheel/jekyll-simple-urls) for a more primitive approach). The basic idea there is to selectively replace `/foo/index.html` with `/foo.html` as needed.

```
module Jekyll
   class Post
       # Obtain destination path, using clean URLs if requested.
       #
       # By default, Jekyll will treat /:title permalinks the same as /:title/,
       # using a destination file of /:title/index.html.  Instead, we change the
       # destination file to /:title.html if clean URLs are requested.
    def destination_with_clean_urls(dest)
       path = destination_without_clean_urls(dest)
      path.sub!(/\/index.html$/, '.html') if clean_urls?(permalink)
      path
    end

    alias_method :destination_without_clean_urls, :destination
    alias_method :destination, :destination_with_clean_urls
```

Then you can use MultiViews or a simple rewrite (or go full-hog and serve extensionless HTML files) to make sure that requests for `/foo` yield `/foo.html`. If you're using `jekyll serve` or the `connect` middleware through Yeoman you'll need to make a couple additional tweaks but that's the idea.